# MySQL Partitioning: Simultaneous insertion to different partitions performance

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a partitioned InnoDB mysql table, and I need to insert hundreds of millions of rows.

I am currently using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command for loading many (think 10's of thousands) of .csv files into said table.

**What are the performance implications if I simultaneously insert large blocks of data into different distinct partitions?**

**Might I benefit from running multiple processes which each run batches of `LOAD DATA INFILE` statements?**

---

Miscellaneous information:

Hardware:  Intel i7, 24GB ram, Ubuntu 10.04 w/ MySQL 5.5.11, Raid 1 storage

#mysql on freenode IRC have told me that the performance implications will be the same as with normal InnoDB or MyISAM - InnoDB will do row-level locking and MyISAM will do table-level locking.

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `short_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `specific_info` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_inquiry` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_paid` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_record` (`short_name`,`specific_info`,`date_of_inquiry`),
  KEY `short_name` (`short_name`),
  KEY `underlying_quotedate` (`short_name`,`date_of_inquiry`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50500 PARTITION BY LIST  COLUMNS(short_name)*/
(PARTITION pTOYS_R_US VALUES IN ('TOYS-R-US') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION pZAPPOS VALUES IN ('ZAPPOS') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION pDC VALUES IN ('DC') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION pGUCCI VALUES IN ('GUCCI') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 ...on and on...
);
```

Comment: "Might I benefit from running multiple processes which each run batches of LOAD DATA INFILE statements?" I Don't know, I know it works that way with inserts, but I don't know 'about load data infile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full list, but some pointers...

The fastest way to insert rows is to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

If that's not an option and you want to speed up things, you'll need to find the bottleneck and optimize for that.
If the partitions are across a network, network traffic might kill you same for CPU, disk I/O and memory, only profiling a sample will tell.

**Disable key updates**
If you cannot do `load data infile` make sure you disable key updates

```
ALTER TABLE table1 DISABLE KEYS
... lots of inserts
ALTER TABLE table1 ENABLE KEYS
```

Note that `disable key updates` only disables non-unique keys, unique keys are **always** updated.

**Binary log**
If you have the binary log running, this will record all those inserts, consider disabling it, you can disable it with MySQL running by using a symlink and pointing that to `/dev/null` for the duration of the mass insert.
If you want the binary log to persist, you can do a simultaneous insert to a parallel database with `blackhole` tables and binary log enabled.

**Autoincrement key**
If you let MySQL calculate the autoincrement key this will create contention around the key generation. Consider feeding MySQL a precalculated autoincrementing primay key value instead of `NULL`

**Unique keys**
Unique keys are checked on every insert *(for uniqueness)* and they eat a lot of time. Because MySQL needs to do a full scan on that index on every insert.
If you know that the values that you insert are unique, it's better to drop that requirement and add it after you are done.
When you add it back in MySQL will take a lot of time checking, but at least it will do it only once, not on every insert.

Comment: I am doing the inserts with LOAD DATA INFILE already.  I will clarify this in my question.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, since I am using the MySQL 5.5 feature of partitioning on a varchar, I don't actually have a primary key on the table.  I know not having a PK is generally ill-advised, but this I don't really need to have one, and there are restrictions with partitioning whereby every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression, See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html.  I will provide more specific detail on my table structure in my question.

Comment: @pyrony, Oh yes you do have a PK, if you don't have one MySQL makes one for you behind the scenes, so the PK autoincrement contention issue still applies to you.

Comment: okay, so how about if I were to make that unique constraint be a primary composite key?  Would that allieviate some of the contention?

Comment: @pyrony, not really/yes a bit *(take your pick)* it will only solve the contention on the autoincrement primary key, which is a small percentage of the time spend compared to the uniqueness test for that composite key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get maximum I/O performance from it you'll want the different partitions on different disks volumes.

I'm not sure about the performance implications if all of the partitions are on the same physical disks but obviously you're more likely to run out of I/O capacity that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to depend on your machine specs, but for what it's worth I've tried this and it definitely speeds things up for my specific task.  Ie, it takes me about an hour to load all the data into one partition. If I don't partition, I have to perform the task serially so it takes 12 * 1 = 12 hours. However, on my machine with 24 cores, I can parallelize the task to complete in just 1 hour.